# How to extend Shape class in paperjs to create new shapes like polygon

Tags: paperjs

I want to extend Shape class in paper.js to draw polygon like pentagon or hexagon
I don't want to use Path.RegularPolygon as it is creating a problem while rotating object along with the path.
Can anyone please provide me sample code on how to extend Shape class to create Polygon in paperjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
var hexagon = new Path.RegularPolygon(new Point(xPos, yPos), 6, radius);
hexagon.rotate( 15 );
paper.view.draw();
```